# Can ASP.NET vNext use non-vNext references?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

So I have a ASP .NET vNext project in VS 14 CTP. I am targeting .NET Framework 4.5.1. I added a reference to a NuGet package, which does not have a build specific for vNext.

Visual Studio now shows usages of the package with no errors in the editor / Intellisense. But when compiling, I get "The namespace 'MyPackage' not found" errors.

It was my understanding that I can add references to .NET Framework assemblies as long as I target the existing .NET Framework 4.5.1. Is this not the case ? Can I resolve this error ?

Comment: Does the NuGet package support 4.5.1?

Comment: Yes it does support 4.5.1.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have both k10 and net451 frameworks listed in project.json, VS 14 by default builds project against both frameworks. In such case if any of the assemblies are not built for k10 framework, build fails with package not found error. So net 451 packages should specifically be added in net451 section of project.json. I am just pasting an example project.json where Microsoft.Bcl package is listed in net451 section

```
{
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-*"
    <more packages>
},
"configurations": {
    "net451": {
        "dependencies": {
            "Microsoft.Bcl": "1.1.9"
            }        
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to completely remove k10 from the configurations list to avoid VS trying to build for k10. Having an empty dependencies list did not help (VS 14 CTP 3). I have edited this answer, so that's clear for anyone reading the answer at a later point in time.

Answer (score 4):

According to [ASP.NET improvements in Visual Studio 2015 CTP 5](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-vs), you will be able to reference standard projects from a vNext project. You can do this by simply using 'Add Reference' menu with right click, or manually adding it to the *project.json* under *dependecies*.

Just **avoid** making cycling references (A references B and B references A) since that will cause Visual Studio to auto refresh the focus of your window on every 5 seconds.