# ASP.NET vNext reference to ADO.NET broken

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a simple ASP.NET vNext class library project which fails to compile when types in System.Data are referenced; what have I done wrong here, or is there a problem in vnext?

I set up my project.json like this:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "System.Data.Common": "1.0.0-alpha3"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "net451": {
            "dependencies": {
            }
        },
        "k10": {
            "dependencies": {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While typing the "System.Data.Common" reference, nuget intellisense worked fine; after saving the file, package restore happened as expected.

Then I added an interface to the project which references `System.Data.IDbConnection`, like this:

```
using System.Data;

namespace MyProj.Common.Data
{
    public interface IDbConnectionFactory
    {
        IDbConnection CreateConnection();
    }
}
```

This bombs at build time:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'IDbConnection' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\Administrator\Proj\MyProj\MyProj.Common\Data\IDbConnectionFactory.cs   7   9   MyProj.Common

My KVM list:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Proj\MyProj [next +3 ~2 -0 !]> kvm list

Active Version            Runtime Architecture Location                             Alias
------ -------            ------- ------------ --------                             -----
  *    1.0.0-alpha3       svr50   x64          C:\Users\Administrator\.kre\packages default
       1.0.0-alpha3       svr50   x86          C:\Users\Administrator\.kre\packages
       1.0.0-alpha3       svrc50  x64          C:\Users\Administrator\.kre\packages
       1.0.0-alpha3       svrc50  x86          C:\Users\Administrator\.kre\packages
       1.0.0-alpha4-10364 CLR     amd64        C:\Users\Administrator\.kre\packages
       1.0.0-alpha4-10364 CLR     x86          C:\Users\Administrator\.kre\packages
       1.0.0-alpha4-10364 CoreCLR amd64        C:\Users\Administrator\.kre\packages
       1.0.0-alpha4-10364 CoreCLR x86          C:\Users\Administrator\.kre\packages
       1.0.0-alpha4-10365 CLR     amd64        C:\Users\Administrator\.kre\packages
       1.0.0-alpha4-10365 CLR     x86          C:\Users\Administrator\.kre\packages


C:\Users\Administrator\Proj\MyProj [next +3 ~2 -0 !]>
```

The [Can ASP.NET vNext use non-vNext references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585016/can-asp-net-vnext-use-non-vnext-references) question seems very similar, but the error message here is somewhat different, and the nuget intellisense suggests that the ADO.NET packages are built for K10.

Comment: i should try vNext now :)

Comment: Just a tip is to use the command "kpm build" if you get build errors and have multiple runtimes defined in your project.json. It is easier to see which run time is failing, sometimes only one fails to build because of a bad reference. Hope they improve this before VS14 is released.

Comment: Nice tip, @AndersNS.  I also am hoping for improved compiler warnings/errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IDbConnection is defined in System.Data.dll in the desktop version of .NET. It is not included in System.Data.Common, which contains only a subset of the ADO.NET types that will be available across different versions of the runtime. If you are ok with your application being able to work only against desktop .NET you should be able to reference the full System.Data.dll and use any types from it. If you want to be able to target the CoreCLR based runtime you should stick to types defined in System.Data.Common, e.g. in this case you can use DbConnection.

Comment: Ok, it appears that the build works for CLR.  It also appears that `System.Data.Common` has a dependency on `System.Data`.  Are there any plans to release a CoreCLR-compatible version of the rest of ADO.NET?   I could do what you suggest and just stick to types in `System.Data.Common`, but if all of `System.Data` will be available at some point, I'd rather just restrict myself to building for CLR for the time being.

Comment: System.Data.Common is a NuGet package that implements a unified portable contract across the different versions of the runtime. I contains different assemblies in separate folders for different target platforms, each of which implements the contract in the way that is more adequate for that platform. Since desktop .NET already includes System.Data.dll (and a whole ecosystem of ADO.NET providers depend on it), the most adequate way for that particular case is to forward the types of the contract to the actual types in System.Data.dll. The NuGet package for SqlClient will work similarly.

Comment: On the other hand, for CoreCLR there is no type forwarding but the contract is implemented directly. The plan is to keep System.Data.Common as a subset and not to bring the whole ADO.NET into it. We have worked on identifying what types were necessary and we are intentionally keeping it minimal. That said, if you have any feedback on types that you think should be there that are currently missing, let us know.

Comment: do y'all have jabbr channel for ADO/EF?

Comment: I am trying to see if a library I have written to abstract ADO.NET will be able to run on coreCLR. CommandType and DbType are not provided in System.Data.Common, what is the alternative?

Comment: @divega Why exactly aren't ADO.NET's interfaces, i.e `IDbConnection`, `IDbCommand` and friends not available in CoreCLR? These impl-free interfaces should be the first types that's made available, the implementations can be different, but not breaking every ADO.NET DAL in existence should be very high on the priority list.